# Winform apps on Windows 10 IOT core running raspberry pi 3

Tags: winforms, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have a winform application running on Windows CE 6.0. I want to upgrade the OS to Windows 10 IOT core running on the raspberry pi 3 without doing much changes in the winform application. I have read that winforms are not supported on Win 10 IOT core. However winforms are supported on .NET core 3.0 and .NET core 3.0 supported on Win 10 IOT core. Does it mean that winform apps are supported on Win 10 IOT core?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Windows IoT Core is a UWP centric OS and UWP apps are its primary app type. Even .Net Core 3.0 is supported on Windows IoT Core, and Windows IoT Core supports .Net Core, it does not mean Windows IoT Core supports WinForm. Please see this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore#non-uwp-apps).